# Can't get projection Object from query, repository returns onbject with null fields

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, projection

I'm trying to get a List of projection objects from the repository, but get Objects with null fields. If I try to return BoardGame objects itself, the repository returns normal objects. What can be wrong? I have a similar method with the UserInfo projection, it works fine.

My query method:

```
@Query("select game from user u " +
        "inner join u.collections c " +
        "inner join c.boardGameCollection bgc " +
        "inner join bgc.boardGame game " +
        "where u.id = ?1 and c.collectionType = ?2")
List<BoardGameInfo> getBoardGameByCollectionTypeAndUserId(long userId, CollectionType type);
```

Hibernate log:

```
select
    boardgame4_.id as id1_0_,
    boardgame4_.bgg_id as bgg_id2_0_,
    boardgame4_.description as descript3_0_,
    boardgame4_.max_player_number as max_play4_0_,
    boardgame4_.max_time as max_time5_0_,
    boardgame4_.min_player_number as min_play6_0_,
    boardgame4_.min_time as min_time7_0_,
    boardgame4_.name as name8_0_,
    boardgame4_.name2 as name9_0_,
    boardgame4_.picture as picture10_0_,
    boardgame4_.tesera_id as tesera_11_0_,
    boardgame4_.tesera_url as tesera_12_0_ 
from
    user appuser0_ 
inner join
    user_collections collection1_ 
        on appuser0_.id=collection1_.user_id 
inner join
    collection collection2_ 
        on collection1_.collections_id=collection2_.id 
inner join
    board_game_collection boardgamec3_ 
        on collection2_.id=boardgamec3_.collection_id 
inner join
    board_game boardgame4_ 
        on boardgamec3_.board_game_id=boardgame4_.id 
where
    appuser0_.id=? 
    and collection2_.collection_type=?
```

BoardGame entity:

```
@Table(name = "board_game")
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor    
public class BoardGame {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String name2;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
    private String description;
    private String teseraUrl;
    private String picture;
    private long teseraId;
    private long bggId;
    private int minPlayerNumber;
    private int maxPlayerNumber;
    private int minTime;
    private int maxTime;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Play> plays = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private Set<BoardGameCollection> boardGameCollections = new HashSet<>();
}
```

BoardGame projection:

```
public interface BoardGameInfo {
Long getId();
Long getBggId();
String getDescription();
int getMaxPlayerNumber();
int getMaxTime();
int getMinPlayerNumber();
int getMinTime();
String getName();
String getPicture();
long getTeseraId();
Set<BoardGameCollectionInfo> getBoardGameCollections();
Set<PlayInfo> getPlays();
interface BoardGameCollectionInfo {
    Collection getCollection();
    Date getAdded();
}
interface PlayInfo {
    long getId();
}
```

}

Other classes:

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "board_game_collection")
public class BoardGameCollection implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "board_game_id")
    @ManyToOne
    BoardGame boardGame;

    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "collection_id")
    @ManyToOne
    Collection collection;

    Date added;
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Collection {

    public Collection() {
    }

    public Collection(CollectionType collectionType) {
        this.collectionType = collectionType;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne()
    private AppUser appUser;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "collection")
    private Set<BoardGameCollection> boardGameCollection = new HashSet<>();

    @Enumerated
    private CollectionType collectionType;

}

@Entity(name = "user")
@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AppUser {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String providerId;
    private String adapter;
    private String email;
    private String firstName;
    private String secondName;
    private String teseraProfile;
    private String avatarUrl;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private Set<Place> places;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "appUser", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Event> events = new HashSet<>();

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Roles> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    @JoinTable(name = "user_plays",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "plays_id"))
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private Set<Play> plays = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private Set<Collection> collections = new HashSet<>();


    private boolean active;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH},
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private City city;

    public Collection getCollectionByType(CollectionType type) {
        Collection collection;
        if (collections.size() == 0) {
            collection = new Collection(CollectionType.OWN);
            collections.add(collection);
        } else {
            collection = this.getCollections()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(c -> c.getCollectionType().equals(CollectionType.OWN))
                    .findFirst()
                    .get();
        }
        return collection;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have tried to log the queries?

Comment: I added logged query, it's the same

Comment: In your logged query I can see an inner join to `user_collections`. Correct me if I'm wrong but I don't see that table in your actual query?

Comment: It's a join table. I use the hql syntax so there isn't this table in my query.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like column alias are different from your projection interface method names.

Try explicitly mentioning the column aliases. Like this,

```
@Query("select game.id as id, game.name as name, game.bggId as bggId from user u " +
        "inner join u.collections c " +
        "inner join c.boardGameCollection bgc " +
        "inner join bgc.boardGame game " +
        "where u.id = ?1 and c.collectionType = ?2")
```

Reference: [spring-jpa-doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces.open.bean-reference) , [blog](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections)

> Note that recursive projections only work if we traverse from the owning side to the inverse side. Were we to do it the other way around, the nested projection would be set to null.

Comment: I have tried to leave only the getId() method in the BoardGameInfo interface. With "select game.id as id" it works properly, but I don't understand why it doesn't work correctly if I write only "select game". 
I have tried to rewrite the query in reverse order "select game from BoardGame game inner join game.boardGameCollections bgc "... etc, but for some reason, nothing was returned

Comment: I have appended some references to my answer.